# When using WinRAR.exe from CLI, how to tell it "don't return back the command prompt until job is done"

Tags: rar, winrar

I'm using WinRAR to compress a big folder into rar in the CLI on windows, something like:

```
winrar.exe a $output_path $input_path
```

It works, but I noticed that the command prompt is immediately returned back, while the job continues in the background until it's done, which takes a long time. There's also no progress indicator in stdout (like 7z.exe has).

I've tried **with and without** the `-ibck` (run in background) switch, the CLI behavior is the same - the command prompt is immediately given back. The only difference is when not using `-ibck`, a small WinRAR GUI window pops up.

The job I'm doing is part of a bigger pipeline in a powershell script. The subsequent steps should run *after* winrar is finished, not in parallel. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Use a CLI version of the RAR archiver. WinRAR isn't it. With few exceptions, executables on Windows are either GUI or CLI. I'm not familiar with WinRAR so I cannot provide more specifics, sorry.

Comment: I believe winrar comes with a cli to use specifically for this, could be rar.exe or something else. Similarly how 7z.exe is actually the cli version, and you have 7zfm (7-zip file manager) that is its gui version.

Comment: @LPChip - in my WinRar installation, the command line Rar.exe is `C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe` and if I run it without params it says `RAR 6.23 x64   Copyright (c) 1993-2023 Alexander Roshal   1 Aug 2023` at the top and gives a list of options & switches.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey thanks. Yeah, so rar.exe is what you want to use for CLI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the folder of winrar.exe, there is also a rar.exe. This is the Command Line Interface (CLI) version that you should use instead of winrar.

It will not show a GUI but do everything using a command prompt window instead.

While the command is running, it will wait for the archiving to complete before going to the next instruction.

rar.exe can also be used in Powershell. Here is an example that uses your syntax: `.\rar.exe a $inputpath $outputpath`

Answer (score 1):

If, for some reason, you do not want to use the CLI version rar.exe, you can start winrar (or any other windows GUI program) with `start /wait winrar.exe`.